# Purpose of geoip Data file

Tags: geoip

Hi I'm very new to Tor and I was wondering if someone could help me understand what the purpose or function of the file:

`/root/tor-browser_en-US/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/geoip`

Answer (score 1):

Since you're new, the first place to find the answers to your questions is to check is the [documentation page](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/documentation.html.en).

From the [Tor Manual](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en): "A filename containing IPv4 GeoIP data, for use with by-country statistics."

Answer (score 0):

Just provision of the country-based filtering, nothing more. As usual, actually - it's not Tor-specific and that's what the GeoIP for. A hint for you: you can purchase the paid subscription from MaxMind for GeoIP and try to feed these files to Tor - and the accuracy improves greatly